# Not able to figure out the problem with my code

Tags: linked-list

**A leetcode problem about Remove Duplicates from Sorted List**[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw0YG.jpg)
Ive been trying to solve this leetcode problem number 83. I am not able to find the mistake in my code or logic, seems I'am doing some silly mistake.

```
    class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* deleteDuplicates(ListNode* head) {
        if(head == NULL)
            return NULL;
        
        ListNode* p = head;
        ListNode* q = head->next;
       
        
        while(q != NULL){
            if(p->val == q->val){
                p->next = q->next;
                ListNode* temp = q;
                q = q->next;
                delete temp;
                        
            }
            else
                q = q->next;
                p = p->next;
        }
        return head;
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to inconsistent indentation, you have the impression that the `else` block has two statements, but it only has one.

Use braces to make it a statement block.